# Is a license needed for Visual Studio Build Tools in order to install Node.JS for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I am interested in incorporating Node.js into Visual Studio code. During the setup process, I received a request to install Python 2, Visual Studio Build Tools, and Chocolatey so that certain npm modules could be compiled from C/C++.

My goal is to maintain Visual Studio Code as a free option for producing commercial code (not that I envision this happening in the foreseeable future), and am wondering whether I would need a paid license from Microsoft to install Visual Studio Build Tools.

Thank you!

[Image as part of setup process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TRAC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Code is always free for private or commercial users. But from your question, you are going to be wondering into the world of Visual Studio by adding its Build Tools.

Yes you might need a paid version because, although there is a free version of Visual Studio, it has limited features.

Visual Studio Build tools might require a license from you before operation.

Happy Coding :)